# Generating HTML Link From Given Values in Form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to generate a link from given values in a form that will allow the user that follows the resulting link to go directly to a certain area of a website based on the information they enter.  However, when I try my current method, the web application kicks out the user when they follow the link because the span tag is being left behind in the link and it perceives it as malicious.
Here's what I have as of now:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
      <head lang="en">
  <title>Example Link Generator</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <script language="JavaScript">
       function showInput() {
            document.getElementById('displaycust').innerHTML = 
                document.getElementById("cust").value;
            document.getElementById('displayjob').innerHTML = 
                document.getElementById("job").value;
            document.getElementById('displaysite').innerHTML = 
                document.getElementById("site").value;             
            document.getElementById('displayname').innerHTML = 
                document.getElementById("name").value;               

        }
      </script>

      </head>
    <body>

      <form>
      <legend><b>Example Link Generator</b></legend>
        <br>
        <br>
        CustId= (Cengage is default):<br>
        <input type="text" name="cust" maxlength="40" id="cust"     value="AC2BB2C8AD16284FA51A8D42D7D1D526">
        <br><br>
        JobId=:<br>
        <input type="text" name="job" maxlength="40" id="job" value="">
        <br><br>
        Site (07 is Offset, 13 is Digital):<br>
        <input type="number" name="site" maxlength="2" id="site" value="07">
        <br><br>
    Name (Used as link display text):<br>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="">
<br><br>


      </form>

      <input type="submit" onclick="showInput();"><br/><br>
      <label><b>Link (highlight and copy):</b></label>
      <p>


    <!-- Problem area-->
      <a href="https://example.com/Site/Pages/Login.aspx?Language=en&Brand=&targetpage=https://example.com%2fSite<span id='displaysite'></span>%2fPages%2fJob%2fJobSummary.aspx%3fCustId%3d<span id='displaycust'></span>%26JobId%3d<span id='displayjob'></span>"><span id='displayname'></span>
    </a>
    <!-- End problem area -->

      </p>
    </body>
    </html>

    <br><br><br><br>
      <span id='displaycust'></span><br><br>
      <span id='displayjob'></span><br><br>
      <span id='displaysite'></span><br><br>
```

When I try to generate a link without display text, clicking on the link will still kick the user out of the web application, but highlighting the text, then copying and pasting the link to the address bar, successfully logs the user in.
That method looks like this:

```
        <!-- Current method without display name for link -->
    https://example.com/Site/Pages/Login.aspx?Language=en&Brand=&targetpage=https://example.com%2fSite<span id='displaysite'></span>%2fPages%2fJob%2fJobSummary.aspx%3fCustId%3d<span id='displaycust'></span>%26JobId%3d<span id='displayjob'></span>"
    <!-- End current method -->
```

I would like to be able to generate a link with display text, but eliminate any residual markup language in the resulting URL.

For example, this would be a bad link:

https://example.com/Site/Pages/Login.aspx?Language=en&Brand=&targetpage=https://example.com%2fSite%3Cspan%20id=%27displaysite%27%3E%3C/span%3E%2fPages%2fJob%2fJobSummary.aspx%3fCustId%3d%3Cspan%20id=%27displaycust%27%3E%3C/span%3E%26JobId%3d%3Cspan%20id=%27displayjob%27%3E%3C/span%3E

This would be a good link:

https://example.com/Site/Pages/Login.aspx?Language=en&Brand=&targetpage=https://example.com%2fSite07%2fPages%2fJob%2fJobSummary.aspx%3fCustId%3dAC2BB2C8AD16284FA51A8D42D7D1D526%26JobId%3dAC2BB2C8AD16284FA51A8D42D7D1D526"

Any help in solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a span tag inside of an HTML attribute, such as the link.

A better approach would be to concatenate the results in JavaScript, then set the link value to the concatenated result

Edit: Here's a code example of my answer:

```
function showInput() {
    var cust = document.getElementById("cust").value;
    var job = document.getElementById("job").value;
    var site = document.getElementById("site").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;

    var generatedLink =
        'https://example.com/Site/Pages/Login.aspx?Language=en&Brand=&targetpage=https://example.com%2fSite'
        + site
        + '%2fPages%2fJob%2fJobSummary.aspx%3fCustId%3d'
        + cust
        + '%26JobId%3d'
        + job;

    var elementThatYouAreEditing = document.getElementById('displayname');
    elementThatYouAreEditing.href = generatedLink;
    elementThatYouAreEditing.innerText = name;
}
```

and your `a` tag would be

```
<a href="" id="displayname"></a>
```

Note that I'm not saying this is the best way to do this, merely a way to do it.

Comment: That's perfect.  I was on my way to fixing it at your original suggestion, but I like the method from your edit much better.  Thank you, very much.